# Find the index of every instance of n in ndarray using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an 2d array, and I'd like to invert 0 to 1 and vice versa, but **only on the first row**.

I have an example below on how to do it, but it affects the entire ndarray.

```
np.where((a==0)|(a==1), a^1, a)
For example:

a = np.array([[0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,1]])
print(a)
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])

np.where((a==0)|(a==1), a^1, a)
```

Input:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Current output:

```
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Use:

```
In [1753]: a[0] = 1 - a[0]

In [1754]: a
Out[1754]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

OR

```
In [1738]: a[0] = np.where((a==0)|(a==1), a^1, a)[0]

In [1739]: a
Out[1739]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

OR use `np.logical_not`:

```
In [1744]: a[0] = np.logical_not(a[0]).astype(int)

In [1745]: a
Out[1745]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use indexing by NumPy if possible, not other modules like `np.where`:

```
mask_0 = a[0] == 0
# [ True False  True False]

mask_1 = a[0] == 1
# [False  True False  True]

a[0, mask_0] = 1
# [[1 1 1 1]
#  [1 0 0 1]]

a[0, mask_1] = 0
# [[1 0 1 0]
#  [1 0 0 1]]
```

if you have just `0` and `1` in the array (besides the [**porwal asnwer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820069/13394817) that is very easy to use i.e. `a[0] = 1 - a[0]`) you can convert to Boolean array based on that as:

```
bool_a = a[0].astype(bool)
# [False  True False  True]

res = ~bool_a                 # inverted
# [ True False  True False]

res.astype(int)
# [1 0 1 0]

a[0] = res.astype(int)
# [[1 0 1 0]
#  [1 0 0 1]]
```

that can be written in one line as:

```
a[0] = (~a[0].astype(bool)).astype(int)
```